# Sum Working With Subset in R

Tags: r, sum, mean

What is incorrect about the following code?

```
TotalCnt<- sum(subset(Dataset,Group=="Test")$Fall_2016_Fall,na.rm=TRUE)
```

It shows up as `0L`.

I think the following code is working though:

```
TotalMN <- mean(subset(Dataset,Group=="Test")$Fall_2016_Fall,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Maybe it is a matter of `rm = TRUE` should not be in the summation?

Also, I will next be subsetting by two conditions moving forward, so I would place `&`  after my `Group == "Test"`? So I would say something like the following:

```
TotalCnt<- sum(subset(Dataset,Group=="Test"&Group2=="XYZ")$Fall_2016_Fall,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Would that work?

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it is hard to say why your code returns 0. Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248)

Comment: Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(Dataset)` or if it's too big `dput(head(Dataset, 20))`. As for the code it seems right. And yes, you would put the conjunction `&` right there.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the input - it turns out that I was using an incorrect variable.
It is quite good to know that my code was OK though.
Under these circumstances should I remove the post, or may I leave it up as it also has great advice about how to properly frame the question with reproducible examples & dput()?